# R- iterating over variables names using a loop or function

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I want to loop over variables within a data frame either using a for loop or function in R.  I have coded the following (which doesn't work):

```
y <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
var1 <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
var2 <- c("m","m","n","n","n","n","o","o","o","m")

mydata <- data.frame(y,var1,var2)

myfunction <- function(v){
  regressionresult <- lm(y ~ v, data = mydata)
  summary(regressionresult) 
}
myfunction("var1")
```

When I try running this, I get the error message:

`Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ v, data = mydata, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'v')`

I don't think this is a problem with the data, but with how I refer to the variable name because the following code produces the desired regression results (for one variable that I wanted to loop over):

`regressionresult <- lm(y ~ var1, data = mydata)
 summary(regressionresult)`

How can I fix the function, or put the variables names in the loop?

[I also tried to loop over the variables names, but had a similar problem as with the function:

```
for(v in c("var1","var2")){
  regressionresult <- lm(y ~ v, data = mydata)
  summary(regressionresult)  
}
```

When running this loop, it produces the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ v, data = mydata, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'v')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: replace your `lm` line with `regressionresult <- lm(y ~ get(v), data = mydata)`

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste` to create the formula to pass it on the `lm`

```
myfunction <- function(v){
  regressionresult <- lm(paste0('y ~', v), data = mydata)
  summary(regressionresult) 
}
out1 <- myfunction("var1")
```

Or use `glue::glue`

```
myfunction <- function(v){
  regressionresult <- lm(glue::glue('y ~ {v}'), data = mydata)
  summary(regressionresult) 
 }
myfunction("var1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions in the `tidyverse` to work with tidy data and applying model to different formulas.

```r
y <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
var1 <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
var2 <- c("m","m","n","n","n","n","o","o","o","m")

library(tidyverse)
mydata <- data_frame(y,var1,var2)

res <- mydata %>%
  # get data in long format - tidy format
  gather("var_type", "value", -y) %>%
  # we want one model per var_type
  nest(-var_type) %>%
  # apply lm on each data
  mutate(
    regressionresult = map(data, ~lm(y ~ value, data = .x))
  )
res
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   var_type data              regressionresult
#>   <chr>    <list>            <list>          
#> 1 var1     <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm>        
#> 2 var2     <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm>
summary(res$regressionresult[[1]])
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ value, data = .x)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -0.7500 -0.3333  0.2500  0.3125  0.6667 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)   0.3333     0.3150   1.058    0.325
#> valueb        0.3333     0.4454   0.748    0.479
#> valuec        0.4167     0.4167   1.000    0.351
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.5455 on 7 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.1319, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1161 
#> F-statistic: 0.532 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.6094
```

Broom package can help you work with the result then

```r
library(broom)
#> Warning: le package 'broom' a été compilé avec la version R 3.4.4
res <- res %>%
  mutate(tidy_summary = map(regressionresult, broom::tidy))
res         
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   var_type data              regressionresult tidy_summary        
#>   <chr>    <list>            <list>           <list>              
#> 1 var1     <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm>         <data.frame [3 x 5]>
#> 2 var2     <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm>         <data.frame [3 x 5]>
```

You can get one of the summary

```r
res$tidy_summary[[1]]
#>          term  estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#> 1 (Intercept) 0.3333333 0.3149704 1.0583005 0.3250657
#> 2      valueb 0.3333333 0.4454354 0.7483315 0.4786436
#> 3      valuec 0.4166667 0.4166667 1.0000000 0.3506167
```

or unnest to get a data.frame to work with.

```r
res %>% 
  unnest(tidy_summary)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   var_type term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 var1     (Intercept)    0.333     0.315     1.06    0.325
#> 2 var1     valueb         0.333     0.445     0.748   0.479
#> 3 var1     valuec         0.417     0.417     1.000   0.351
#> 4 var2     (Intercept)    0.333     0.315     1.06    0.325
#> 5 var2     valuen         0.417     0.417     1       0.351
#> 6 var2     valueo         0.333     0.445     0.748   0.479
```

Functions of interest are `nest` and `unnest` from [`tidyr`][http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) that allow to create list columns easily, `map` from [`purrr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) that allows to iterate over a list and apply a function (here `lm`) and `tidy` from [`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) package that offers functions to tidy results from models (summary results, predict results, ...)

Not used here but know that [`modelr`](https://modelr.tidyverse.org/) package helps for doing pipelines when modeling.